# Vim onedark Colorscheme not Loading, But Exists

Tags: vim, plugins, vim-plugin, color-scheme, iterm2

I currently use Iterm2, and Vim 7.4 with the Minimalist Vim Plugin Manager. While opening a file through Vim, I get the error:

```
Error detected while processing MYDIRECTORY/.vimrc:
line 19:
E185: Cannot find color scheme 'onedark'
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

The [onedark](https://github.com/joshdick/onedark.vim) theme doesn't load, but if, in Vim, I type `:colorscheme onedark`, it loads perfectly.

My .vimrc is as follows:

```
set t_Co=256
set autoindent
set mouse=a
set number
set shiftwidth=0
set tabstop=4

"let g:airline_theme='onedark'

"Use 24-bit (true-color) mode in Vim/Neovim when outside tmux."
if (has("nvim"))
let $NVIM_TUI_ENABLE_TRUE_COLOR=1
endif
if (has("termguicolors"))
set termguicolors
endif

set background=dark
colorscheme onedark
syntax on

call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')

"Make sure you use single quotes

"ATOM Text Editor Default Syntax Theme"
Plug 'https://github.com/joshdick/onedark.vim.git'

"Shorthand notation; fetches https://github.com/junegunn/vim-easy-align
Plug 'junegunn/vim-easy-align'

"Any valid git URL is allowed
Plug 'https://github.com/junegunn/vim-github-dashboard.git'

"Multiple Plug commands can be written in a single line using |
"separators
Plug 'SirVer/ultisnips' | Plug 'honza/vim-snippets'

"On-demand loading
Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree', { 'on': 'NERDTreeToggle' }
Plug 'tpope/vim-fireplace', { 'for': 'clojure' }

"Using a non-master branch
Plug 'rdnetto/YCM-Generator', { 'branch': 'stable' }

"Using a tagged release; wildcard allowed (requires git 1.9.2 or
"above)
Plug 'fatih/vim-go', { 'tag': '*' }

"Plugin options
Plug 'nsf/gocode', { 'tag': 'v.20150303', 'rtp': 'vim' }

"Plugin outside /.vim/plugged with post-update hook
Plug 'junegunn/fzf', { 'dir': '/.fzf', 'do': './install --all' }

Plug 'https://github.com/exvim/ex-autocomplpop'

"Initialize plugin system
call plug#end()
```

What should I do?

Comment: Use formatting tools to make your post more readable. Code block should look like `code block`. Use **bold** *italics* if needed and image should be added as image , not as a link.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The way vim-plug works is this:

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
```

creates a bunch of functions/commands and sets a bunch of options,

```
Plug 'https://github.com/joshdick/onedark.vim.git'
```

adds that resource to an internal list,

```
call plug#end()
```

actually installs all your plugins in `~/.vim/plugged` if they are not there and sets up your `:help 'runtimepath'` to the correct value that tells Vim where to look for plugins.

So, basically, you can't expect a plugin installed by vim-plug to be available *before* vim-plug did its magic.

Moving `colorscheme onedark` *below* `call plug#end()` should solve your problem.

Comment: Great suggestion and explanation. Thanks!

Comment: thanks a lot, the key is Moving colorscheme setting after plug#end()